# catkin_make fails in tf tutorial

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Following the TF tutorial http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/TF

catkin_make does not make the files. I tried catkin_make robot_setup_tf as well and get the following result:
dave@canbot:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make robot_setup_tf
Base path: /home/dave/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/dave/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/dave/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/dave/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/dave/catkin_ws/install

##### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/dave/catkin_ws/build"

##### Running command: "make -j4 -l4 robot_setup_tf" in "/home/dave/catkin_ws/build"

make: *** No rule to make target `robot_setup_tf'.  Stop.
Invoking "make" failed

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66786/catkin_make-fails-in-tf-tutorial/) by [Dave Everett](https://answers.ros.org/users/427/dave-everett/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2013-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, make sure that you have sourced the workspace, i.e.

```
source %TOP_DIR_YOUR_CATKIN_WS%/devel/setup.bash
```

Second, check that you have created package in a right directory, i.e. `%TOP_DIR_YOUR_CATKIN_WS%/src`. I think there may be a mistake in tutorial, since it telling you to change to `%TOP_DIR_YOUR_CATKIN_WS%`.

Finally, if these are correct, and your package is within `%TOP_DIR_YOUR_CATKIN_WS%/src`, but you still cannot change to it with `roscd robot_setup_tf`, then do `rospack profile` and try again.

If you followed [beginner tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace) then `%TOP_DIR_YOUR_CATKIN_WS%` will be `~/catkin_ws`.

Hope it helps.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2013-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4